# New typescript type derived from literals that generates a compilation error when assigned to simple literal or other types

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

To avoid mixing all my variables typed number with each other, I want to add an additional layer of security by typing them in a way that would generates a compilation error if I try to assign a literal number or another type to this new type.

You can see that as giving a unit to my variables, for instance "second" and "meter". They both are derived from the literal type "number", but I shouldn't be able to add a variable typed second with one typed meter.  I shouldn't neither be able to assign a variable of type second to another one of type meter.

```ts
let length1   =  5 as Meter;
let length2   =  7 as Meter;
let duration1 = 10 as Second;
let duration2 = 11 as Second;

let lengthSum = length1 + length2         // should type lengthSum as Meter and give it a value of 12
let durationSum = duration1 + duration2   // should type durationSum as Second and give it a value of 21

length1 = duration2                // should generate an error
let foo = length1 + duration1;     // should generate an error
```

By extension, I would also like to do the same with strings:

```ts
let myBookTitle = "Best title ever" as Title;
let myBookAuthor = "John Doe" as Author;

myBookTitle = myBookAuthor // should generate an error
```

.

I have tried with the following custom types:

```ts
type Meter = number & { __type: 'meter' };
type Second = number & { __type: 'second' };
```

They work for most cases but miss the mixed addition case:

```ts
let length1 = 5 as Meter;
let length2 = 10 as Meter;
let duration1 = 2 as Second;
let duration2 = 3 as Second;

length1 = length2; // works as expected
length1 = duration1; // generates an error as expected

let length10 = (length1 + length2) as Meter; // works but is not able to automatically infer the length10 type with the "as Meter"
let length11 = (duration1 + duration2) as Second; //same as above

let length12 = (length1 + duration2) as Second; // Shouldn't allow such addition but does it without any error!!
```

Would anyone know how to create a new type that covers all my constraints?
(I know there are some npm packages that cover specifically the SI units, but that is not what I am looking for. Units are used here as examples; I will need to handle multiple types of différents types outside "simple" units. Thanks.)

Comment: This isn't possible (yet).

Comment: You can't overload the behavior of native numerical operators; you'd need some kind of `add` function or method.  Do you want an answer presenting such an alternative approach?  Or just a "no this is not possible" answer with a link to the relevant feature request at [ms/TS#42218](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42218)?

Comment: @jcalz - Thank you for your answer. An alternative approach would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkyAw) maybe?  If so I'll add it to the answer I write up; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. If I correctly understand your example, you have deported the security of the operation in the signature of the add method. While this generates the errors where they are expected, you have to force yourself to use an otherwise unneeded function that will not be suggested by the autocompletion since it is not linked to the newly created types. If there is no way to do this through type, I think a class would be a better fit, what do you think?

Comment: Sure, but then you're not going to have plain numbers at runtime.  If that's fine then maybe [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mMzjkW) would be more useful? I'm thinking this might be somewhat out of scope, though, since there are lots of possible ways to refactor with upsides and downsides, whereas the real answer to this question is probably "until and unless ms/TS#42218 is implemented then you'll need to do it some other way".  I'm happy to mention such an alternative but I don't know that we want to spend a lot of effort designing and discussing it in the answer.  Shall I proceed?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Thank you for the answer. The facts are that there is no "clean" and native solution currently and ms/TS#42218 may be the answer eventually. Your first answer is a good enough approach (with some downsides) if needed. Another solution is to go through classes, but then, that is another story. If that is ok for you, you can proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible as asked.  The TypeScript behavior of native JavaScript operators like [the addition operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) is baked into the language and you can't override or customize it. So if you write `x + y` where `x` and `y` are some subtype of `number`, you will get a plain `number` out, undoing any [nominal-like type branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) you've applied.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42218](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42218) to be able to essentially [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) signatures for these operators, but until and unless such a feature is implemented there's no way to do this.

---

For now there are only workarounds.  The particular workaround you use is probably out of scope for the question, but here are some possibilities that might be useful as a starting point:

You can't customize operator behavior, but you  *can* customize *function* behavior, so if you want you can wrap operators in functions and then use the functions instead:

```
function add<T extends number>(t1: T, t2: T): T {
    return t1 + t2 as T;
}

let length10 = add(length1, length2);
//  ^? let length10: Meter
let length11 = add(duration1, duration2);
//  ^? let length11: Second
let length12 = add(length1, duration2); // error
```

Obviously this isn't ideal, since you need to remember to use `add()` instead of `+`.

Or, you could refactor to use classes holding number values instead of the numbers directly:

```
class BrandedNumber<T extends string> {
    constructor(public __type: T, public value: number) { }
    add(other: BrandedNumber<T>) {
        return new BrandedNumber(this.__type, this.value + other.value);
    }
}
const Meter = (value: number) => new BrandedNumber("meter", value);
const Second = (value: number) => new BrandedNumber("second", value);
let length1 = Meter(5);
let length2 = Meter(10);
let duration1 = Second(2);
let duration2 = Second(3);
length1 = length2; // okay
length1 = duration1; // error
let length10 = length1.add(length2);
//  ^? let length10: BrandedNumber<"meter">
let length11 = duration1.add(duration2);
//  ^? let length11: BrandedNumber<"second">
let length12 = length1.add(duration2); // error
```

which also isn't ideal, especially if you care about preserving the runtime behavior (presumably you wouldn't want to do any computation-intensive processing that wraps and unwraps numbers like this).

Again, the particular workaround one chooses depends on one's use cases and isn't really in scope here; the main point is that without operator overloading, a workaround is necessary.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1ATiGMJoGIFdh4AXASwHtgkBvAKCQaWIE9skBZCYnJAXiWD4wAIx4AyGkgD6UltgBcSAOSRuaJUgC+AbnqM5yAMoR4lACZ8BQ0WiQTq02awiKlUE+Y07aehgBsuJADgAHNiAAsARksAViQQKA4uHF1GIMDgsPCAJktIgAZ4xM41VMYA4iQzfAwySmj+XISkY1NgMzL-QOraimBc-gBmIpaPdt1fdNCIhqms7O0kAHolpAB3cjQAa0TmiAAPbBIIM0nMmcsekDrgSMWVpBCIYBxr6HiqHDRNkYOj7lOkwAZoQSH14mYzAAeAAqSAO3HaiUEIhwAD4ABTESKKGEAGiY2VxAEpcTRJmk0FwalRsUgANSEkYwzpaHxpCpzGaFfggSEY85RAmC7LE1kPJAAPQA-GcMs8spFZnyzBirjdIgT1X1ReLVlLZRz5dMogMIarBZqqjVrjqxctVl9NrRND5QJBYAhkABhPwJdyJOhpeB+qCJABCGHaJwActYcLD4ftEWZElBiGhSKE0eS0sHKOm0PgSJsMTB8MI-KR4I4DLiCeXK9WkAA3EB+fAuKyotDEySuvOMFUY8gRHCKSMgaNmOM92FovtBwd5qnEGkCCBrJCT6ezmxY8KkKAAOhkBgJESPx7bHeQjNH4Rw1-bnbFFMYA4-kza6aSaksGI3p2igojYfa8DmLxbjuZixvGaAYgARKoOCIQSQEQG++bAL+rTmABGEgfB4GQZu25RrBM7wUh7htGYaGti+mGspylqWCUOAYjEWHlMa8zsckCEFDxXSVNq9SWHh7QYrqcpiTaNxmlJqqDCJXJRJYIr3Ks5BbCAzByiaszibc2nwmg3xoHJ6kFJpCozMew4impEoyuklSWvkE4UXBc7IYJiFotZlrGQpfSRI5-ImbJaSudK7k2Ti5FTpRe4JohtHmIFwX2aadlGZFqrRfaDxOlZmhAA)